# zeppelin 8-SNAPSHOT helium not loading from local repository

Tags: apache-zeppelin, helium

I am using the current Zeppelin - 0.8.0 Snapshot from today Dec 6 2017. I am trying to modify a helium module for Zeppelin. I have loaded the three files needed into zeppelin/helium/ but when I go to the helium page there are no Helium modules listed.

If I delete the helium directory the helium modules hosted on npm show back up.

I put these three files in a helium directory I created under the zeppelin directory:
index.js, package.json, volume-leaflet.json

Where do the errors show up for this?

I also tried running these commands:
    cd zeppelin-web
    yarn run dev:helium
As indicated on:
https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT/development/helium/writing_visualization_basic.html

Then I tried port 9000 but still the helium module does not show up.

Thanks for the help.

brad

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out the answer.

Do not put all the files that compose the helium module into the zeppelin/helium directory.

Only place the helium package file in the helium directory. In this case volume-leaflet.json file. This file points to another location where the code for the helium module you are building lives.

In the development directory which can be anywhere else place the package.json and the javascript file and other code files.

Then you make another json file with the name of your helium module into the zeppelin/helium directory. And make sure the archive: directive is pointed at the path where the development code is.

If you have the wrong files in the zeppelin/helium directory none of the Helium modules will work.

Also if your helium module has the same name as one hosted at npm it will not show up. I had to change the name to volume-leaflet-dev to get it to show up.